# Set CORS-headers if (cache) file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I have the following .htaccess config to redirect the user to a cached version of an API response:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/$ - [E=URL:$1]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:URL}.json -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:URL}.json [L]
```

The `URL` environment variable is set to account for the trailing slash that may or may not exist. This part works perfectly and does what its supposed to do.

However, since the requests are made via AJAX-calls, we are required to set CORS headers for these cases. It is important that these headers are NOT set if there is no cached response.

I've tried the following things, but none worked.

Using an `If` block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/$ - [E=URL:$1] [PC]

<If "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:URL}.json'">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Accept"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type,Content-Length"
</If>
```

Using `setEnvIfExpr`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/$ - [E=URL:$1] [PC]

setEnvIfExpr "-f '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/${ENV:URL}.json'" USE_CACHE

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=USE_CACHE
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Accept" env=USE_CACHE
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" env=USE_CACHE
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type,Content-Length" env=USE_CACHE
```

Note that in both cases, if I replace `%{ENV:URL}` with a hardcoded file that exists, the headers are set as expected in the last example.

For some reason, `%{ENV:URL}` is not available in these conditional expression?

I've been trying so many things and none of them seemed to work for something this trivial.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We just managed to solve this issue.

Apparently, mod_rewrite and mod_headers are two separate modules that run in the "wrong" order for the above code to work.

This is how we solved the problem for anyone else that needs this:

```
# Redirect to a cached version of the resource if its available.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [E=MY_CACHED_URL:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.json]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ - [E=MY_CACHED_URL:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.json]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MY_CACHED_URL} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{ENV:MY_CACHED_URL} [L]

# Set CORS headers for cached results.
SetEnvIfExpr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/cache/.+#" IS_CACHED=1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CACHED
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type,Accept" env=IS_CACHED
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" env=IS_CACHED
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Type,Content-Length" env=IS_CACHED
```